# Scala - Write data to file with row limit

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD with 30Million rows of data, Is there a way to save this into files of 1M each.

Answer (score 0):

I think their is no direct way of doing it. one thing you can do is *collect()* your rdd and get the iterator from it and save it using normal file save using what scala provides. Something like this

```
val arrayValue = yourRdd.collect();
//Iterate the array and put it in file if it reaches the limit .
```

**Note:**  This approach is *not recommended if your data size id huge* because collect() will bring all the records of RDD to driver code(Master).

Comment: my data is around 30M i want to write 1M per file

Comment: Okay. can you please update your question?  Numbers are little misleading  .

Answer (score 0):

You can do `rdd.repartition(30)`. This will ensure that your data is about equally partitioned into 30 partitions and that should give you partitions which have roughly 1 Mil rows each.

Then you do simple `rdd.saveAsTextFile(<path>)` and Spark will create as many files as partitions under `<path>`. Or if you want more control over how and where your data is saved, you can do `rdd.foreachPartition(f: Iterator[T] => Unit)` and handle the logic of actually dealing with rows and saving then as you see fit within the function `f` passed to the `foreachPartition`. (Note that `foreachPartition` will run on each of your executor nodes and will not bring the data back to driver, which of course is a desirable thing).